# How to set up kube-proxy on Amazon EC2 non-master managed instance?

Tags: kubernetes

The goal for setting up the kubernetes kube-proxy on another EC2 instance would be for the network configuration (iptables) to propagate there. So that instance would not be a minion and could take requests from internet and because of its kube-proxy managed iptables, the requests would be forwarded to correct kubernetes services.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Install an extra node in your cluster and then go in and remove the kubelet from the extra node (if you are using salt you should be able to reconfigure the salt to not include the kubelet). This will leave you with a kube-proxy that is configured with the location of the master and that is babysat by monit.

Option 2: Download just the kube-proxy binary and run it manually. You should be able to look at the command line arguments it's been passed on one of the nodes in your cluster and clone them. Remember to run it as root.